# Open URL in native browser from simple WebView-App

Tags: javascript, ios, web-applications, safari, native

I have an (native) app which just represents a simple WebView (iOS) that directs to a webpage. Is it possible to open some URLs from that webpage with the native iOS browser (Safari)?

Following code does not work, but works great in an PhoneGap app (which also basically represents just a WebView):

```
window.open(twitter_url, '_system');
```

Answer (score 0):

You are goint o have to call back into the Native portion of code from your javascript and call something like this:

```
NSURL *url = [ [ NSURL alloc ] initWithString: @"http://www.Google.com" ];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

You can get this call from javascript into your native code by overloading the function

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
```

In the UIWebview Delegate.  Then parse the load request and run the launch function above based on the response.  How you word that launch request is up to you.